# « Off the record » et « officieux »

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, usage, anglicismes

Comment dit-on « off the record » en français ?

Peut-on employer la locution telle quelle ? Ou bien la locution un peu plus francisée *hors du record* ?

Doit-on employer une autre traduction parmi [celles données par linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/off+the+record.html)?

De quel registre sont « officieux » et « officieusement » ?

> Littré écrit pour *officieux* : Se dit, par opposition à officiel, de ce
>   qui a le caractère de simple communication de la part du gouvernement.
>   Des renseignements officieux, non officiels.

Comment « officieux » a obtenu ce sens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comme toutes les traductions, un contexte est bienvenu, voire indispensable, mais à défaut, *officieux* est un bon candidat.

> Peut-on employer la locution telle quelle ?

Guère.

> Ou bien la locution un peu plus francisée *hors du record* ?

Encore moins. C'est un contresens. La traduction mot à mot serait « non enregistré ».

> De quelle registre est « officieux » ?

Courant ou formel. Il n'y a pas de problème à l'employer dans la plupart des circonstances.

> Comment « officieux » a obtenu ce sens ?

**Officieux** (*officiosus*: qui rend service) est l'antonyme d'**officiel** (*officialis*: qui concerne une charge, une fonction).  Source [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4579)

Answer (score 2):

En communication, on distingue la discussion publique, celle destinée a être entre entendue par tous et la discussion ***privée***, celle destinée à rester entre les interlocuteurs.

Mon opinion est donc que la meilleure traduction pour *conversation off the record* ou *en off*, (record étant ici pris pour *enregistrement*) est : *conversation **privée***.

*officieux* à pris ce sens justement parce qu'il est opposé à *officiel*. Or, ce qui est *officiel* étant nécessairement public, à l'opposé, ce qui est officieux... ne le sera pas.
Il est curieux d'ailleurs d'observer que le sens ancien employait ce mot au sens moral de *serviable, obligeant*... Traduire *off the record* par *officieux* rendrait alors les deux sens simultanément... privé et... pour rendre service comme on *donne un tuyau* quoi... ;-)

Mais... je dis ça... je dis rien... ;-)